# Footnotes under table in landscape mode

Tags: tables, footnotes, landscape

I have a table in landscape mode and do footnotes like this:

```
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newgeometry{top=5cm, outer=-1cm, inner=0cm, bottom=8.5cm}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Analyse der Verlanisierungen}
\label{analyseTabelle}
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{2cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{8cm}|l|p{1cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Rap} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Verlanisation} & \multicolumn{1}{C{3cm}|}{Französisches Pendant} & \multicolumn{1}{C{1cm}|}{Silben (phon.)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Bildungsverfahren} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Wortklasse} & \multicolumn{1}{C{3cm}|}{Lexikalisiert im P.R.\footnotemark 2015} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Semantisches Feld} \\ \hline
1 & \textit{caille-ra} & \textit{racaille} & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & identification, immigration \\ \hline
1 & \textit{mille-fa} & \textit{famille} & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & identification, origine \\ \hline
1 & \textit{ton-bâ} & \textit{bâton} & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & délinquance, violence \\ \hline
1 & \textit{ston-ba} & \textit{baston} & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & délinquance, violence \\ \hline
2 & \textit{keufs} & \textit{flics} & 2 & Geschlossener Einsilber mit \enquote{\textit{e muet}} und Apokopierung \textit{flic > [flik] > [k\oe fli] > [k\oe f]} im Plural. & Substantiv Sg. & ja\footnotemark &  délinquance, violence\\ \hline
2 & \textit{foncedé} & \textit{défoncé} & 3 & Phonetischer Dreisilber; vorher dreisilbig,  hinterher zweisilbig; \textit{defoncé  > [f\textopeno \~sde]}. & Verb & nein & vie quotidienne \\ \hline
2 & \textit{blèmes-pro (3x)} & \textit{problèmes} & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Pl. & nein & problématique de l'argent \\ \hline
2 & \textit{ive} & \textit{vie} & 1 & Offene Einsilber, Inversion von Konsonantenlaut und Vokallaut. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & vie quotidienne \\ \hline
2 & \textit{illeu-cou} & \textit{couille} & 2 & Einsilber mit Halbvokal als Endung mit \enquote{\textit{e muet}} zu Zweisilber; Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & vie quotidienne, délinquance \\ \hline
3 & \textit{keums} & \textit{mecs} & 2 & Geschlossener Einsilber mit \enquote{\textit{e muet}} und Apokopierung \textit{mec > [k\oe m\textepsilon] > [k\oe m]} im Plural. & Substantiv Pl. & ja\footnotemark & vie quotidienne, identification \\ \hline
3 & \textit{keufs} & \textit{flics} & 2 & Geschlossener Einsilber mit \enquote{e muet} und Apokopierung \textit{flic > [flik] > [k\oe fli] > [k\oe f]} im Plural. & Substantiv Pl. & ja\footnotemark & délinquance, violence \\ \hline
3 & \textit{ris-Pa} & \textit{Paris} & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & problématique de l'argent \\ \hline
3 & \textit{tro-mé} & \textit{métro} & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & vie quotidienne \\ \hline
3 & \textit{rées-soi} & \textit{soirées} & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Pl. & nein & vie quotidienne \\ \hline
3 & \textit{ur} & \textit{rue} & 1 & Offene Einsilber, Inversion von Konsonantenlaut und Vokallaut.  & Substantiv Sg. & nein & problématique de l'argent \\ \hline
3 & \textit{troms} & \textit{métros} & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber mit Apokope und im Plural (vgl. \cite{Merle2006}: 52f). & Substantiv Pl. & nein & vie quotidienne \\ \hline
3 & \textit{trom} & \textit{métro} & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber mit Apokope (vgl. \cite{Merle2006}: 52f). & Substantiv Sg. & nein & vie quotidienne \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\footnotetext{a footer}
\footnotetext{another footer}
\footnotetext{another footer2}
\footnotetext{another footer3}

\restoregeometry
\end{landscape}
```

I use \footnotemark and later \footnotetext.
But my result looks like this:

[image]

The table is forced on the next page. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Please indicate how the macro `\textopeno` and the columntype `C` are defined.

Comment: \textopeno is defined by \usepackage{tipa}. I don't know what C defined. But you can see my preamble here: http://pastebin.com/fpMEzWqr

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My three main suggestions are as follows.

- Load the `rotating` package and use a `sidewaystable` environment instead of messing about with `\newgeometry`.
- Load the `threeparttable` package with the option `para`. Use `\tnote{...}` in the body of the table to set footnote markers via `\tnote` directives, and use a `tablenotes` environment to typeset the contents of the footnotes. The `para` option serves to typeset all footnotes in a single row, which saves a lot of (vertical) space.
- Load the `tabularx` package to make use of the available horizontal space as much as possible (which is `\textwidth`), and use an `X`-type column that's headed by "Bildungsverfahren".

In addition, I'd really strive to give the table a more open and inviting "look", mainly by getting rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines. Executing `\setlength\extrarowheight{1.5pt}` helps too.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,inner=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[french,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' environment
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\def\TPTtagStyle{\textit} % table footnote markers in italics
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,tipa}
\usepackage{calc} % for \widthof macro
\usepackage[skip=0.25\baselineskip]{caption}

\usepackage{csquotes,booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}

\setlength\extrarowheight{1.5pt} % provide a bit more vertical whitespace
\footnotesize
\captionsetup{size=footnotesize}

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Analyse der Verlanisierungen}
\label{analyseTabelle}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
   l 
   >{\em}L{\widthof{Verlanisation}} 
   >{\em}L{\widthof{Französisches}} 
   L{1cm} 
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X 
   l 
   L{2cm} 
   L{\widthof{vie quotidienne,}} @{}}
%\hline
\toprule
Rap & 
\textup{Verlanisation} & 
\textup{Französisches Pendant} & 
Silben (phon.) & 
Bildungsverfahren & 
Wortklasse & 
Lexikalisiert im P.R. 2015\tnote{a} & 
Semantisches Feld \\ %\hline
\midrule
1 & caille-ra & racaille & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & identification, immigration \\ %\hline
1 & mille-fa & famille & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & identification, origine \\ %\hline
1 & ton-bâ & bâton & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & délinquance, violence \\ %\hline
1 & ston-ba & baston & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & délinquance, violence \\ %\hline
2 & keufs & flics & 2 & Geschlossener Einsilber mit \enquote{\textit{e~muet}} und Apokopierung \textit{flic > [flik] > [k\oe fli] > [k\oe f]} im Plural. & Substantiv Sg. & ja\tnote{b} &  délinquance, violence\\ %\hline
2 & foncedé & défoncé & 3 & Phonetischer Dreisilber; vorher dreisilbig,  hinterher zweisilbig; \textit{defoncé  > [f\textopeno \~sde]}. & Verb & nein & vie quotidienne \\ %\hline
2 & blèmes-pro (3x) & problèmes & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Pl. & nein & problématique de l'argent \\ %\hline
2 & ive & vie & 1 & Offene Einsilber, Inversion von Konsonantenlaut und Vokallaut. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & vie quotidienne \\ %\hline
2 & illeu-cou & couille & 2 & Einsilber mit Halbvokal als Endung mit \enquote{\textit{e~muet}} zu Zweisilber; Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & vie quotidienne, délinquance \\ %\hline
3 & keums & mecs & 2 & Geschlossener Einsilber mit \enquote{\textit{e~muet}} und Apokopierung \textit{mec > [k\oe m\textepsilon] > [k\oe m]} im Plural. & Substantiv Pl. & ja\tnote{c} & vie quotidienne, identification \\ %\hline
3 & keufs & flics & 2 & Geschlossener Einsilber mit \enquote{e~muet} und Apokopierung \textit{flic > [flik] > [k\oe fli] > [k\oe f]} im Plural. & Substantiv Pl. & ja\tnote{d} & délinquance, violence \\ %\hline
3 & ris-Pa & \textit{Paris} & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & problématique de l'argent \\ %\hline
3 & tro-mé & métro & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & vie quotidienne \\ %\hline
3 & rées-soi & soirées & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Pl. & nein & vie quotidienne \\ %\hline
3 & ur & rue & 1 & Offene Einsilber, Inversion von Konsonantenlaut und Vokallaut.  & Substantiv Sg. & nein & problématique de l'argent \\ %\hline
3 & troms & métros & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber mit Apokope und im Plural (vgl.\ \cite{Merle2006}: 52f). & Substantiv Pl. & nein & vie quotidienne \\ %\hline
3 & trom & métro & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber mit Apokope (vgl \cite{Merle2006}: 52f). & Substantiv Sg. & nein & vie quotidienne \\ %\hline
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a]{a footer}
\item[b]{another footer}
\item[c]{another footer2}
\item[d]{another footer3}
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, this looks really great! But there is one thing that was better in the landscape mode. When reading the document digitally I I need to turn my head 90° to read the table. Or is it because I made a mistake, implementing your code? --> https://www.overleaf.com/5929199bzpzrj

Comment: @texNewbie - I guess this depends on your pdf previewer. Can you set up your pdf previewer to rotate landscape-mode pages automatically, so that you don't have to crane your neck? (I rotated the page by 90 degrees before posting the screenshot shown above.)

Comment: Okay I will check that. Another thing, how can I make the sidewaytable be exactly where I want it. I tried [p] etc. but it is always a page to far behind.

Comment: @texNewbie - If it's "always a page to[o] far behind", try positioning its material a page sooner. :-) Note: `sidewaystable` material will always be placed on a page by itself.

Comment: Oh I fixed it myself with \clearpage after the table.

Answer (score 1):

- After sixt and half years for your table can be used `talltblr` of `tabularray` package.
- By using `tabularray` is simpler to set (nicer) table layout and achieve that table can fit in page text box.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,inner=3cm]{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,tipa}
\usepackage[french,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes,ragged2e}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}   % new
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' environment
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{sidewaystable}
\footnotesize
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}

    \begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Analyse der Verlanisierungen},
  label = {analyseTabelle},
 note{} = {\begin{enumerate*}[label=\textsuperscript{\alph*}, itemjoin={,\quad}]
            \item   a footer
            \item   another footer
            \item   another footer 
            \item   another footer
            \end{enumerate*}
          }         ]{cells = {font=\linespread{0.82}\selectfont},
                      colsep  = 5pt,
                      colspec = {@{} c Q[l, font=\itshape] Q[l, font=\itshape] 
                                     c X[j] l l Q[l, wd=23mm] @{}},
                      row{1}  = {font=\rmfamily, m},
                      rowsep  = 1.5pt
                      }
    \toprule
Rap &   Verlanisation
        &   {Französisches\\ Pendant} 
            &   {Silben\\ (phon.)} 
                &   Bildungsverfahren 
                    &   Wortklasse 
                        &   {Lexikalisiert\\ im P.R. 2015\TblrNote{a}}
                            &   {Semantisches\\ Feld}   \\
    \midrule
1 & caille-ra & racaille & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & identification, immigration  \\ 1 & mille-fa  & famille  & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & identification, origine      \\ 
1 & ton-bâ    & bâton    & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & délinquance, violence        \\
1 & ston-ba   & baston   & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & délinquance, violence        \\ 
2 & keufs     & flics    & 2 & Geschlossener Einsilber mit \enquote{\textit{e~muet}} 
                               und Apokopierung \textit{flic > [flik] > [k\oe fli] > [k\oe f]} im Plural. 
                                                       & Substantiv Sg. & ja\TblrNote{b} 
                                                                             &  délinquance, violence       \\
2 & foncedé  & défoncé  & 3 & Phonetischer Dreisilber; vorher dreisilbig,  hinterher zweisilbig;
                              \textit{defoncé  > [f\textopeno \~sde]}. 
                                                     & Verb           & nein & vie quotidienne              \\ 
2 & blèmes-pro (3x) 
            & problèmes & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Pl.  & nein & problématique de~l'argent    \\
2 & ive     & vie       & 1 & Offene Einsilber, Inversion von Konsonantenlaut und Vokallaut. 
                                                    & Substantiv Sg.  & nein & vie quotidienne              \\
2 & illeu-cou 
            & couille  & 2 & Einsilber mit Halbvokal als Endung mit \enquote{\textit{e~muet}} zu Zweisilber;
                             Inversion Zweisilber.  & Substantiv Sg.  & nein & vie quotidienne, délinquance \\
3 & keums   & mecs     & 2 & Geschlossener Einsilber mit \enquote{\textit{e~muet}} und Apokopierung
                             \textit{mec > [k\oe m\textepsilon] > [k\oe m]} im Plural. 
                                                    & Substantiv Pl.  & ja\TblrNote{c} 
                                                                             & vie quotidienne, identification \\ 
3 & keufs   & flics    & 2 & Geschlossener Einsilber mit \enquote{e~muet} und Apokopierung 
                             \textit{flic > [flik] > [k\oe fli] > [k\oe f]} im Plural. 
                                                    & Substantiv Pl.  & ja\TblrNote{d} 
                                                                             & délinquance, violence        \\
3 & ris-Pa & \textit{Paris} & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & problématique de~l'argent \\
3 & tro-mé & métro & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Sg. & nein & vie quotidienne \\ %\hline
3 & rées-soi & soirées & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber. & Substantiv Pl. & nein & vie quotidienne \\ %\hline
3 & ur & rue & 1 & Offene Einsilber, Inversion von Konsonantenlaut und Vokallaut.  & Substantiv Sg. & nein & problématique de~l'argent \\ %\hline
3 & troms & métros & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber mit Apokope und im Plural (vgl. \cite{Merle2006}: 52f). & Substantiv Pl. & nein & vie quotidienne \\ %\hline
3 & trom & métro & 2 & Inversion Zweisilber mit Apokope (vgl. \cite{Merle2006}: 52f). & Substantiv Sg. & nein & vie quotidienne \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\lipsum[3-9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for not upvoting sooner -- I wasn't aware of your answer until just today.

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much! I do not remember when I upvote you nice answer!